# Unit testing Dart async stream

Tags: unit-testing, async-await, dart

I am trying to create a list in Dart that sends events each time an object is added or removed from it, and I'm having trouble figuring out how to write a unit test for it.

Here's the code for the list:

```
enum Action { Insert, Modify, Remove }

class ListChangeEvent {
  final int index;
  final Action action;
  final PathComponent component;

  ListChangeEvent(this.index, this.action, this.component);
}

class PathComponentList extends DelegatingList<PathComponent> {
  final List<PathComponent> _list = [];

  @override
  List<PathComponent> get delegate => _list;

  var changeController = new StreamController<ListChangeEvent>();
  Stream<ListChangeEvent> get onChange => changeController.stream;

  @override
  void add(PathComponent value) {
    super.add(value);
    changeController
        .add(new ListChangeEvent(this.indexOf(value), Action.Insert, value));
  }
}
```

Now what I'd like to do is create a unit test to verify that each time I insert an element, I get a ListChangeEvent delivered in the stream.

Here's my current attempt. This hangs forever, I'm sure because I never close the stream.

```
void main() {
  group('PathComponentList', () {
    PathComponentList list = PathComponentList();
    var body = PathComponent(Path.Body);
    var chance = PathComponent(Path.Chance);
    var crossroads = PathComponent(Path.Crossroads);

    setUp(() async {
      list = PathComponentList();
    });

    test('should fire event when adding', () async {
      list.add(body);
      list.add(chance);
      list.add(crossroads);

      List<ListChangeEvent> events = await list.onChange.toList();
      expect(events[0].action, equals(Action.Insert));
      expect(events[0].index, equals(0));
      expect(events[0].component, equals(body));
    });
  });
}
```

I've tried to get individual element from the stream like this:

```
await list.onChange.elementAt(index);
```

But if I do this more than once, the code complains that I've already listened to the stream.

Since I want the stream to send ListChangeEvents for the lifetime of the application, what is the best way to read the three ListChangeEvents that are written to this stream in my unit test?

Comment: Nit: don't assign `list` in this line `PathComponentList list = PathComponentList();` – leave it null!

Comment: Yeah, I would have eventually seen that. The code started off without a setup() method; I forgot to fix this when I refactored. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem: the events have already "left" by the time you register your `onChange` listener.

Try this: (modified since I don't have your `PathComponent` type)

```
test('should fire event when adding', () async {
  // Queue up the adds to happen after we listen for the change event
  Timer.run(() {
    list.add(body);
    list.add(chance);
    list.add(crossroads);
  });

  var events = await list.onChange.take(3).toList();

  expect(events[0].action, equals(Action.Insert));
  expect(events[0].index, equals(0));
  expect(events[0].component, equals(body));
});
```

Comment: Thanks. Should have been obvious. I also didn't see the take(count) method of Stream. That's exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Nice, but how am I supposed to test the initial value of a stream? If I init the stream with a boolean: true, for example. Didnt find a way, since when I write the expect, the stream is already populated

Comment: I think that this answer is misleading.  I think that the critical part of the fix is to use `.take(3)` to close the `Stream` after reading 3 events, which fixes the problem of waiting forever.  The remark about "events have already left" would be true for a *broadcast* stream, but that isn't the case here.  And if it were a broadcast stream, I think a better approach would be to separate registering the listener from `await`ing it: `var future = streamController.stream.take(3).toList(); streamController.add(whatever); var events = await future;`